# Facebook - assign username to a variable by calling FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo()

Tags: facebook

I am developing a facebook app and I seem to have got stuck on an issue.

I am trying to assign the username to a variable by calling the below code, but the variable is returning null.

```
var current_user ='';
var arUser = FB.Connect.get_loggedInUser();
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(arUser, ["name"], 
  function (user, exec) 
  { //alert(user[0].name); - this works!!
  current_user = user[0].name; 
});

alert(current_user); // this returns null :(
```

I get a value if I do an alert(user[0].name) within the function. I get a feeling that I need to wait for the response from execution of users_getInfo() before using the current_user variable, but not sure how..

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should process the data in the callback function, due to this call is asynchronous.

Comment: isnt that what function(user, exec) is? the last parameter of the FB api calls are usually the (aync/sync) callback function.

Comment: @RPM1984: yes it is. but he is trying to work with data **outside** that callback, which is wrong.

Comment: lol, i didnt even see that last line - alert(current_user). i was looking at current_user = user[0].name - which should work. my bad =)

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert` is being called before the AJAX call returns.  Just wrap code that uses the `current_user` variable in a separate function, and invoke that function only from the `users_getInfo` success handler.

Another option would be to have a timer that polls for the variable, but I see no reason to do such a thing.